# How to implement multiple conditions in my sql query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How to implement a rule like "if both values `[Procedure], cs.[description]` are null from `IsNULL([Procedure], cs.[description]` then use `IsNULL([Procedure], [code]`" in my query?

```
STUFF((SELECT ',' + ISNULL([Procedure], cs.[description])
       FROM [Procedure] pr
       LEFT JOIN [xx].Codeset.CodeDefinition cs 
            ON pr.ProcedureCode COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = cs.code
            AND cs.codeSetId = (SELECT id
                                FROM [xx].CodeSet.CodeSet fc
                                WHERE fc.identifier = 'com'
                                  AND cs.codingSystem LIKE 'I')
       WHERE Type = 'S'
         AND ID = Pc.BID
       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Procedures,'
```

Can someone suggest how to achieve this goal?

Comment: Your question is not clear... can you expand please.

Comment: Do you just want `COALESCE([Procedure], cs.[description], [code])`?

Comment: @DaleK - I have modified my question. Can please provide me complete solution. Thanks

Comment: Did you try what I suggested? `coalesce` allows you to enter more than 2 values, and keeps going until it finds a non-value. As best I can tell it solves your problem - just replace your current `isnull` with my suggested `coalesce`.

Comment: @DaleK, Thank you! It resolved my problem.

Comment: Aside: `cs.codingSystem LIKE 'I'` is a bit curious. Any reason not to use `cs.codingSystem = 'I'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Coalesce.

```
   STUFF((SELECT ',' + Coalesce([Procedure], cs.[description],[code])
       FROM [Procedure] pr
       LEFT JOIN [xx].Codeset.CodeDefinition cs 
            ON pr.ProcedureCode COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS = cs.code
            AND cs.codeSetId = (SELECT id
                                FROM [xx].CodeSet.CodeSet fc
                                WHERE fc.identifier = 'com'
                                  AND cs.codingSystem LIKE 'I')
       WHERE Type = 'S'
         AND ID = Pc.BID
       FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS Procedures
```